# I need to organise two ggpolt bar graphs in R so they both begin with the same month?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I asked a question a while ago and ended up with a beaut bar graph thanks to lots of help from wonderful people on here. The example data I used is:

```
df<-data.frame(month = c("Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"), site = c("Borth", "Borth", "Borth", "Borth", "Borth", "Clarach", "Clarach", "Clarach", "Clarach", "Clarach"), organic = c(10,20,30,40,50), inorganic = c(90,80,70,60,50))
```

I now have this chunk of code:

```
df %>% 
       tidyr::pivot_longer(c("organic", "inorganic")) %>%
       mutate(se = ifelse(name == "inorganic", NA, se)) %>%
       ggplot(aes(x = site, y = value, fill = name)) + 
       geom_col() + 
   geom_errorbar(aes(min = value - se, max = value + se)) +
   geom_text(data = data.frame(site = "Borth", value = 55, name = "organic", 
                               month = "Jul"),
             aes(label = "*"), size = 5) +
   facet_grid(~month) +
   scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste(x, "%")) +
  labs(caption = "*Potential reproductive event")
```

Which makes me a lovely stacked bar chart! I have used this twice, for two separate dfs, however one has only 8 months of data and one 12, and they are ending up with one starting in April and one in September, which when I stack them one above the other makes them hard to compare. Any chance there is a way to define which month is the starting point?

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: I get "Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `se`. x object 'se' not found" when I try to run your code.

Comment: It's probably better to use facets instead of trying to make two separate graphs, please provide both data.frames as you have for `df`. You'll be able to make the months the same by converting them to a factor and use `drop = FALSE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have two data frames: `df1` and `df2` with differing months. First, add a variable denoting the set. Then, combine the data frames using `rbind()` and use `facet_grid(set~month)` in `ggplot`:

```r
df1$set = "Data 1"; df2$set = "Data 2"
df = rbind(df1, df2)

df$month = factor(df$month, levels = c("Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul"))

df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(c("organic", "inorganic")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(se = ifelse(name == "inorganic", NA, se)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = site, y = value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(min = value - se, max = value + se)) +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(site = "Borth", value = 55, name = "organic", 
                              month = "Jul", set = "Data 1"), aes(label = "*"), size = 5) +
  facet_grid(set~month, drop = T) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste(x, "%")) +
  labs(caption = "*Potential reproductive event")
```

[image]

Reproducible example data:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(month = c("Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"), site = c("Borth", "Borth", "Borth", "Borth", "Borth", "Clarach", "Clarach", "Clarach", "Clarach", "Clarach"), organic = c(10,20,30,40,50), inorganic = c(90,80,70,60,50), se = 1:10)
df2 <- subset(df1, ! month %in% c("Mar","Apr"))
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks so much! And thank you for finding the actual reproducible data my bad! One final request - is it possible to choose which month is first on the graph? I'd like it to start in March if possible, at the moment they're in alphabetical order - is there a way I can specify the order of the months? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: ooo and also is it possible to make the labelled reproductive event only in one of the dataframes?

Comment: ooo and also is it possible to make the labelled reproductive event only in one of the dataframes?

Comment: I think you should add the set label into your definition of data in `geom_text()`: `data = data.frame(site = "Borth", value = 55, name = "organic", month = "Jul", set = 1)`

Comment: For the months, create a factor variable and set the levels. I've updated the code and the plot

Comment: so, when I have the geom_text bit in there it reorders my months to alphabetical, but when I take it out they go in the order I defined. Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: Does the code produce a different plot to mine when you copy my code?

Comment: Never mind I fixed it! Thanks for all your help I really appreciate it!!